# incomprehensible result when comparing between id inside array and id NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want return result true, but javascript talking that its false. Could someone explain me why?
here is log with console.log

> 5a8f1df35f65a820f4dc56ed 5a8db5d449c0572dbc60548c
>
> false
>
> 5a91e3de5b8d6d18580c9aff 5a8db5d449c0572dbc60548c
>
> false
>
> 5a91e3f45b8d6d18580c9b00 5a8db5d449c0572dbc60548c
>
> false
>
> 5a8db5d449c0572dbc60548c 5a8db5d449c0572dbc60548c

```
.get('/selected/board', function (req, res) {
    var isExist = false;

    Board.findById({ _id: req.query._id })
        .then((board) => {
            board.users.forEach(element => {
                console.log(element == req.user._id)
                console.log(element, req.user._id) 
            });  
            // res.json(board);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            res.status(404).json('Cant download.')
        })
})
```

**EDIT**

> element: "5a8f1df35f65a820f4dc56ed" req.user._id: "5a8db5d449c0572dbc60548c"
>
> false
>
> element: "5a91e3de5b8d6d18580c9aff" req.user._id: "5a8db5d449c0572dbc60548c"
>
> false
>
> element: "5a91e3f45b8d6d18580c9b00" req.user._id: "5a8db5d449c0572dbc60548c"
>
> false
>
> element: "5a8db5d449c0572dbc60548c" req.user._id: "5a8db5d449c0572dbc60548c"
>
> true
>
> element: "5a8f1df35f65a820f4dc56ed" req.user._id: "5a8db5d449c0572dbc60548c"
>
> false
>
> element: "5a91e3de5b8d6d18580c9aff" req.user._id: "5a8db5d449c0572dbc60548c"
>
> false
>
> element: "5a91e3f45b8d6d18580c9b00" req.user._id: "5a8db5d449c0572dbc60548c"
>
> false
>
> element: "5a8db5d449c0572dbc60548c" req.user._id: "5a8db5d449c0572dbc60548c"
>
> true

Comment: Is that mongoDB and express.js ?

Comment: Maybe you have an extra space in one of the IDs?

Comment: George Campbell, yes       Vasan, no, is okay without extra space

Comment: this is not the answer but maybe you could debug it by using `console.log("element: "+JSON.stringify(element), "req.user._id: "+JSON.stringify(req.user._id))` ?

Comment: Done, look edit, could u explain me why i should use JSON.stringify to compare it?

Comment: when objects are same it's returning true so I don't know what you mean by "but javascript talking that its false". Do you know javascript is asycn though? You can't do console log on different lines and expect it to be in order. i.e true or false may not correspond to the string above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element within `board.users` has an attribute `id`  whose type is `ObjectId("45465456464")`, so the comparison you're executing follows this rule:

```
            +--- Operand ObjectId(...)
            |
            v
ToPrimitive(element) == B  <---- String from the request.
```

So, this condition is always `false`

```
element == req.user._id
```

Take a look at this doc [`Loose equality using ==`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Loose_equality_using)

An alternative is converting to `String`

```
element.toString() == req.user._id
```